# Flutter : Why is the data updated when moving to another activity?

Tags: flutter

**My Flutter Project structure is like this**

```
Main() //Run App with MaterialApp and Routes
L HomePage() //Default route (/), with BottomNavigation
  L MoviesPage() //Default BottomNavigation Index and shows a list of movies form TMDB 
    L DetailsMoviesPage()
  L SeriesPage()
    L DetailsSeriesPage()
  L SupportPage()
    L DetailsSupporPage()
```

The data update was stopped when Navigator between the tab, but when Navigator from `MoviesPage()` to `DetailsMoviesPage()` Or Navigator from `SeriesPage()` to `DetailsSeriesPage()` Or Navigator From
`SupportPage()` to `DetailsSupporPage()` Is building `HomePage()` and All Activity are being updated
As well as when writing on the textfield located in being update `HomePage()`?

```
body: _childnav[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabPressed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex, //this property defines current active tab
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.movie), title: Text('Movies')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.tv), title: Text('Series')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.help), title: Text('Help'))
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Use `Provider` or `Riverpod` state management stuffs.

Comment: One alternative is to use the @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; so your pages only pull the information once, however keep in mind that this alternative only works for tabs or shared widgets in screen.

Comment: probably you are calling ```setState({})``` inside ```onTabPressed``` so this will call ```build``` method which make you widgets build again